# I'm trying to have an ai follow a path but it's not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want a simple circle AI to follow some invisible game objects I have down. It goes to the first one then stops.

I put a debug thing in the second if statement and its not logging. I have also tried changing the second if statement to else.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class FollowPath : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] target;
     public float speed;

private int current = 0;

void Update()
{
    if(transform.position != target[current].position)
    {
        Vector2 pos = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target[current].position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(pos);

    }
   if(transform.position == target[current].position)
    {
        current++;
        Debug.Log("2");
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Try comparing/logging the distance between the two positions instead. Depending on the way Unity compares vectors, it may try to do a float comparison which does not always work as expected. You can read more about it here: https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Comment: No Unity uses a distance comparison ( [==](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html)) but it is very small grained `0.00001f` which might never be fullfilled while moving to much between two frames

Answer (score 3):

You almost never want to compare positions in games for equality, but rather check that they are closer than a reasonably small distance.

Instead of:

```
if(transform.position == target[current].position)
```

try something like this which just checks that you're "reasonably close" as defined by whatever you think is acceptable (0.01f in my example here):

```
if((transform.position - target[current].position).magnitude < 0.01f)
```

Comment: You can simply use `Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target[current].position) < 0.01f`. [==](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_eq.html) actually does kind of the same but with `< 0.00001`